# Tuple keys of a map are converted to another map when using map function to retrieve the keys

Tags: scala

When I ran the following piece of code, I got some unexpected result

```scala
val a = Map(
  ("1", "2") -> 1,
  ("1", "4") -> 2,
  ("2", "2") -> 3,
  ("2", "4") -> 4
)
println(a.size)
val b = a.map(_._1)
println(b.size)
val c = a.keySet
println(c.size)
```

The result is:

```
res0: Int = 4
b: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(1 -> 4, 2 -> 4)
res1: Int = 2
c: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(String, String)] = Set((1,2), (1,4), (2,2), (2,4))
res2: Int = 4
```

What I expected is the content of b is the same as that of c. Is it expected in Scala? Or some kind of side effect?

Comment: You may force `b` to have the same contents of `c` with: `val b = a.map[(String, String)](_._2)` - What is happening here is that the `map` method on a **Map** is overloaded, so if the return type of the function is of type **(K, V)** it will create a new **Map[K, V]**. However, for simplicity if you only want the keys it is always better to use `keys`, `keySet` or `keysIterator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour. As a general rule, Scala's collection `map` methods try to make the output collection the same type as the collection on which the method is called.

So, for `Map.map`, the output collection *can* be a `Map` whenever the result type of the function you pass to `map` is a `Tuple`. This is precisely the case when you call `val b = a.map(_._1)`. At this point, another rule comes into play: a `Map`'s keys must be unique. So, as Scala traverses `a` during the call to `a.map(_._1)`, it inserts the result of `_._1` into the new map that it's building (to become `b`). The second entry replaces the first, and the fourth entry replaces the third, because they have the same key.

If this is not the behaviour you want, you should be able to get round it by decalring the type of `b` to be something other than a `Map`.

e.g.

```scala
val b: Seq[(String, String)] = a.map(_._1)
```

Comment: "As a general rule, Scala's collection map methods try to make the output collection the same type collection on which the method is called." —— Such behaviour could be misleading.

Comment: How so? I'm not disagreeing with you, I'm just trying to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use .keys instead, because you are mapping a Map[(String,String),Int] into a Map[String,String] and since the keys need to be unique, the rest of the Map is discarded.

This happens because you are mapping into this Map[(String,String)] so Scala convert into a Map[String,String]